# Namespace and forward declaration problems

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

I have a problem with forward declarations and namespaces. Following example code:

```
namespace Waalkes
{
   class Otto;
}

namespace Comedian
{
    class MyClass : public ...
    {
        ...
        Waalkes::Otto getFun();
        ...
    }
}
```

This should be no problem normally, "Waalkes::Otto getFun()" refers to forward declaration on top directly. Unfortunately some programmers decided to also have a namespace ""Comedian::Waalkes" that is defined in one of the headers included in this code. So it happens compiler tries to find "Comedian::Waalkes::Otto" which does not exist.

Since it is not an option to get rid of these ugly double used names: what options do I have? Is there a possibility to define getFun() in a way so that its return value refers to the correct namespace "Waalkes::Otto" and not to "Comedian::Waalkes::Otto" because of the enclosing "namespace Comedian"? Some kind of parent-namespace-placeholder perhaps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer specifically to the `Waalkes` namespace in the global namespace with `::Waalkes`. So if you want the `Otto` class in that namespace, do `::Waalkes::Otto`.

However, you'll still have a problem. You can't use an incomplete type as a return type in a function definition.